# Spring @Transactional best practices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

i wanna know if my implementation of `@Transactional` is correct or not.

when I got to know `@Transactional` for the first time, i used it in my repository classes, above each method that makes multiple calls to mongodb at once.
But, i stopped using that approach, and put `@Transactional` above my service classes, so that each method of my services runs in a single transaction. for example, find an object from the database, validate the user input, then modify the object and save it in the database .. knowing that sometimes I  need to throwe a exception, like not found, or bad request...

is my implementation correct?

Comment: this is an opinion based question and will most likely be closed.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: There are no best practices. You use "@Transactional" where do you need transaction to be. Also "@Transactional" has various options so it depends on use case you need.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf this is not an opinion based question, i wanted to know if my implementation is correct or it may cause problems =)

Comment: You should strive to keep transactions as short as possible, while still containing everything that needs to be changed. And "changed" is a keyword, focus on operations that change your data. For instance, if you need to fetch data from an external source, try to keep it outside the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, usually service methods are annotated with @Transactional when you want everything in that method to happen in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will not cause any problem, we use @Transactional operation when we want the statement in the method to happen in one transaction. Generally we use it in service class but even if it is used elsewhere will not give any problem.

If you need a details of how it works can see

https://dzone.com/articles/how-does-spring-transactional